# Create a function / procedure / loop for creating multiple tables of same structure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way of creating multiple tables of same structure either using loop / function / procedure ?
I know there is a method of "like" but I'm looking for other options too for knowledge sake.

example I want to create 5 tables with structure but different names :
table names:
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr

```
    drop procedure if exists create_table;
    DELIMITER //
    create procedure create_table
      (in str varchar(10))
    begin
      set @query = concat('create table str',
                '`col1` varchar(20), `col2` float,',
                '`col3` int(10), `date` date,');'
     execute query;
     end //
     DELIMITER ;

     call create_table(abc)
     call create_table(def)
     call create_table(ghi)
     call create_table(jkl)
     call create_table(mno)
```

Nothing is working because it is only creating a table names as "str".

I hope I'm able to explain, what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. Maybe a more concrete example would help us understand. As an advisory, if you're using a table as a template to stamp out *N* copies of the same structure you're probably doing it wrong. Relational databases aren't intended to be used that way and going down that path usually massively over-complicates things. Use one table with some kind of index column or use table partitioning to separate data.

Comment: Simple said yoes you can using a stored procedures., but you have to use a algorithm for the table names or use a comma seperated string with the table names.

Comment: Seconding the comment by @tadman, if you're even trying this, there is probably a problem (or you are making one for yourself). Simply and a bit crudely put, just add a "fake_table_identifier" column to template table T, and query T with `SELECT * FROM T WHERE fake_table_identifier = whatevertheprocwouldveused`. If you _partition_ by that field, I believe mysql will even store it like it they were separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, it should be

```
    drop procedure if exists create_table;
    DELIMITER //
    create procedure create_table
   (in str varchar(10))
       begin
         set @query = concat('create table,',str,);
         set @query = concat('`col1` varchar(20), `col2` float,',);
         set @query = concat('`col3` int(10), `date` date,');');
    prepare s from @query;
    execute s;
    end //
    DELIMITER ;

   call create_table(abc)
   call create_table(def)
   call create_table(ghi)
   call create_table(jkl)
   call create_table(mno)
```